# Naming columns for data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table of the form

```
   nrow    V1      V2        V3      V4        V5  V6 V7                  V8
 1:    1 chr20     C4b   6382078     C4b   6381944 reg  - Thymus_M_GSM1328751
 2:    2  chr8    Rpl4  68832532    Rpl4  68832743 reg  + Thymus_M_GSM1328751
```

I want to name the columns as ("Chromosome", "Start_Gene","startPosition", "End_gene", "endPosition", "RNAtype", "strand", "replicate"). I tried :

```
ratData <- ratData[, by= list("Chromosome", "Start_Gene","startPosition", "End_gene", "endPosition", "RNAtype", "strand", "replicate")]
```

But it does not work. I also tried key instead of "by".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `setnames` function to change the column names.

```
setnames(ratData, c("nrow", "Chromosome", "Start_Gene","startPosition", "End_gene", 
                    "endPosition", "RNAtype", "strand", "replicate"))
```

Here are a couple variations:

```
setnames(ratData, 
         paste0("V", 1:8), # i.e. c("V1", "V2", ..., "V8")
         c("Chromosome", "Start_Gene","startPosition", "End_gene", 
           "endPosition", "RNAtype", "strand", "replicate"))

setnames(ratData, 
         2:9,
         c("Chromosome", "Start_Gene","startPosition", "End_gene", 
            "endPosition", "RNAtype", "strand", "replicate"))
```

Comment: I believe it should be setNames with a capital N

Comment: @ElPresidente No, `setnames` is a `data.table` function that does not make any copies in memory.

Comment: if you use `paste0` then you don't need `collapse=""`

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Oops.  That should have been `sep=""` instead of `collapse=""`, in which case you are correct that I could use `paste0` instead.  I will update.

Answer (score -2):

'names' function also works:

```
names(ratData)
[1] "nrow" "V1"   "V2"   "V3"   "V4"   "V5"   "V6"   "V7"   "V8"  

names(ratData) = c("nrow", "Chromosome", "Start_Gene","startPosition", "End_gene", "endPosition", "RNAtype", "strand", "replicate")

ratData
   nrow Chromosome Start_Gene startPosition End_gene endPosition RNAtype strand           replicate
1:    1      chr20        C4b       6382078      C4b     6381944     reg      0 Thymus_M_GSM1328751
2:    2       chr8       Rpl4      68832532     Rpl4    68832743     reg      0 Thymus_M_GSM1328751
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, this makes multiple copies of the data, so while it works, it may not be the best approach. `setnames` from "data.table" also works with `data.frame`s.